# Facebook FBConnect and FeedDialog working when Open Graph v1.0 retired?

Tags: facebook, facebook-opengraph, fbconnect

I have an app that controls simple Facebook URL sharing using FBConnect (and therefore FeedDialog). It is used because it does not require the user to be logged in, unlike the native sheet.

Will the forthcoming retirement of v1.0 mean that FBConnect no longer works? The only reference I can see to V1.0 or V2.x is when the username and password authenticates. , prior to sending the URL link. The documentation seems to suggest that FeedDialog is deprecated and may still work but it isn't entirely clear (and does not mention FBConnect).

Comment: Well, what _is_ “FBConnect”? Sounds like (from tag description) an outdated term for one of their SDKs, but I am not sure which one.

Answer (score 1):

FBConnect as you have described has been phased out for a long time. Facebook has transitioned to the Feed Dialog (now being deprecated) and now to the Share Dialog.

It appears based on your use case that the dialog that you should investigate using is the Share Dialog. This does not require you to have users log in to Facebook and provides all the functionality to share your URL's across the devices you use.

The documentation with complete code samples for this is located here with subsequent documentation for implementing on iOS and Android.

https://developers.facebook.com/docs/sharing/reference/share-dialog

This will allow you to share you website URL on all platforms and allowing you to customize which images are shared with the url's and help format how they are displayed on the news feed.